# Select com entity não funciona

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho esse método que me faz um select porém ele não me retorna nada.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public JsonResult GetContratos()
{
     List<object> resultado = new List<object>();
     var contratos = db.Contratos.Where(c => c.Tipo != "N").Select(c => c.Id);

     foreach (string contrato in contratos)
     {
          resultado.Add(new { id = contrato, value = contrato });
     }
     return Json(resultado, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Já tentei colocar o .ToList() no final e nada

O SQL que me é retornado na variavel `var contratos`, quando eu o executo no sql server funciona perfeitamente, me trás dado, mas no c# não me trás nada.

```
{SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[DtCriacao] AS [DtCriacao], 
    [Extent1].[DtInicioValidade] AS [DtInicioValSELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
    FROM [dbo].[Contrato] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  NOT ((N'N' = [Extent1].[Tipo]) AND ([Extent1].[Tipo] IS NOT NULL))
```

Segue a imagem do código sendo executado no banco[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `var contrtatos` fica null?

Comment: Não fica null, esse é o sql que vem dela

Comment: O que ocorre se você retirar o where : `var contratos = db.Contratos.Select(c => c.Id);` ? Tem certeza que você está conectado na base correta?

Comment: Já tentei tirar também, e sim está conectado na base correta

Comment: Não acontece nada quando eu tiro o where

Comment: Está sim, pois ele já está com sistema de login implementado e algumas outras coisas que dependem do banco

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade pode me ajudar?

Comment: Comece com a etapa mais simples. Retorne a lista completa: `var contratos = db.Contratos;`

Comment: Nem isso está retornando nada

Comment: Você tem certeza de que o entity está conectando na mesma base em que você está fazendo a consulta? Ex.: você executa a Query manualmente no SQLServer de homologação, mas a sua aplicação está apontando para um LocalDB ou outra base.